# If cookie is not present, display video

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Just a warning, I am totally new to PHP and coding in general so please bear with me.

**Here is what I am attempting to do:**
Our company's wordpress website ( http://www.vectormedia.com ) uses lightbox to display a video when the homepage is loaded. I'd like to make it so that if you have visited the website in the past week, the video will not appear.

**Here is my code:**

At the very top of the header.php of my wordpress theme is the function to create the cookie:

```
<?php
function cookies() //Sets cookie function for video
{
$expire = time()+60*60*24*7; //cookie expiration (7days)
setcookie("video", "vector", $expire);
}
?>
```

Here is the variable that will load the video embedded in lightbox (also located in header.php):

```
<?php
//defines javaload as lightbox script with embeded video
$javaload = '<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.lightbox("https://www.vimeo.com/36697123");

});
</script>'   
?>
```

Here is the If statement located in the footer.php that checks to see if the cookie exists and if we are on the homepage, if true then load the video and set the cookie:

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_COOKIE["video"])) && (is_front_page());
echo $javaload
echo cookies();
?>
```

The problems are:

a) this code simply doesn't work.
b) it's also breaking my submenu rollovers

And my questions are:

a) why doesn't this work?
b) why is it breaking my menu?
c) is there a better way to accomplish this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not the problem, but don't `echo cookies()`. The cookie function doesn't return anything, so there's nothing to echo out.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response. How would I go about setting the cookie after lightbox has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

semi-colon after:

echo $javaload

and remove the semi-colon after the if statement and use {} for the if tag if you want to only set a cookie when there is no cookie.

Comment: Like this? <?php
if( !isset($_COOKIE["video"])) && (is_front_page())
{
 echo $javaload;
 cookies();
}
?>

Comment: Yes, but I am not exactly sure about the if(), I think it has to be if(!isset($_COOKIE["video"])&&is_front_page()) with the parentheses around the whole expression

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_COOKIE["video"] && is_front_page()) {
echo $javaload;
echo cookies();
}
?>
```

But im not sure thats going to trigger the lightbox in that case you'd have to do it like this

```
<script>
function play_video() {
jQuery.lightbox("https://www.vimeo.com/36697123");
}
</script>
```

then change $javaload to echo out play_video();